# Enable one-click instead of double-click when clicking NavigationViewPaneDisplayMode

Tags: c#, .net, events, uwp, navigationview

#### Introduction

I want to make the header button to be used to minimize items with a one click action, not double one

[Screenshot of the header button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Brb2.png)

#### Source Code

```
    StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();

    InitializeComponent();


    NavigationView navigationView = new NavigationView();
    navigationView.PaneDisplayMode = NavigationViewPaneDisplayMode.LeftMinimal;
    
    navigationView.IsPaneOpen = false;

    NavigationViewItem navigationViewItem = new NavigationViewItem();

      void NavigationView(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        navigationView.IsPaneOpen = true;

    }
    navigationViewItem.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Admin);
    navigationViewItem.Content = "Test";
    


    navigationView.MenuItems.Add(navigationViewItem);

    stackPanel.Children.Add(navigationView);


    Content = stackPanel;
```

#### Problem

I want to run the code when the [header button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Brb2.png)
clicked once, not twice, but I don't know how to change the source code to do that.

Answer (score 0):

By testing, when clicking the header button, items are minimized. The default operation is once click. It works well.

In addition, why did you create UI through code behind? I suggest you could create it through xaml code.
For example:

```
<StackPanel>
        <NavigationView PaneDisplayMode="LeftMinimal" IsPaneOpen="True">
            <NavigationView.MenuItems >
                <NavigationViewItem Content="Test" Icon="Admin" />
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        </NavigationView>
 </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Hello, the problem still exists. If you minimise the window and then click on the header button, it takes two clicks to maximise it.

Comment: In your scenario, I find a method named NavigationView(). Is it a Tapped event of Navigationview? I can’t reproduce your issue.
Could you please give the complete xaml code and code behind for testing?